# Unity game on iOS ArgumentOutOfRangeException in dictionary

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have an achievement module for saving and loading a dictionary with the name of the achievement (key) and if it's been accomplished (bool value). I'm using GDE (Game Data Editor) plugin [(this one)](http://gamedataeditor.com/).

My module works fine in the Unity editor, saving and loading everything. But in iOS it crashes with an argument out of range exception. My save and load methods:

```
    public void Load(){

    GDEAchievementsData achievements;

    if (!GDEDataManager.DataDictionary.TryGetCustom(GDEItemKeys.Achievements_Achievements, out achievements)){
        Debug.LogError("Error reading save data!");
    }

    LoadAchievementsInDictionary(achievements);

    Debug.Log("Achievement loaded data");
}

public void Save(){

    GDEAchievementsData achievements;

    if (!GDEDataManager.DataDictionary.TryGetCustom(GDEItemKeys.Achievements_Achievements, out achievements)){
        Debug.LogError("Error reading save data!");
    }

    SaveDictionaryInAchievements(AchievementScript.achievements, achievements);

    achievements.Set_Achievements();

    Debug.Log("ACHIEVEMENTS saved data");

}

void LoadAchievementsInDictionary(GDEAchievementsData gdeData){

    Debug.Log("Achievements: "+gdeData.Achievements);

    if(achievements==null){
        achievements = new AchievementList();
    }

    foreach(List<String> achievement in gdeData.Achievements){
        if(achievements.list.ContainsKey(achievement[0]))
        {
            achievements.list[achievement[0]] = (achievement[1]=="true")||(achievement[1]=="True");
        }else{
            achievements.list.Add(achievement[0], achievement[1]=="true"||achievement[1]=="True");
        }
    }

}

void SaveDictionaryInAchievements(AchievementList list, GDEAchievementsData gdeData){
    for(int i = 0; i < gdeData.Achievements.Count; i++){
        List<string> item = gdeData.Achievements[i];
        string achievementName = item[0];
        item[1] = list.list[achievementName].ToString();
    }

}
```

And the errors generated in XCode debugger, for saving:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range.
>   Parameter name: index
>     at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String].get_Item (Int32 index) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at AchievementScript.SaveDictionaryInAchievements (.AchievementList list, GameDataEditor.GDEAchievementsData gdeData) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at AchievementScript.Save () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at AchievementScript.OnApplicationFocus (Boolean focusStatus) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at AchievementScript.OnApplicationPause (Boolean pauseState) [0x00000] in :0

And for loading:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range.
>   Parameter name: index
>     at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String].get_Item (Int32 index) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at AchievementScript.LoadAchievementsInDictionary (GameDataEditor.GDEAchievementsData gdeData) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at AchievementScript.Load () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at AchievementScript.OnApplicationFocus (Boolean focusStatus) [0x00000] in :0

Asking the same question for the GDE team, but if anyone has any idea why this is happening, it'd be great to have some enlightenment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple time you access `achievement[0]` and `achievement[1]`, without checking the size of `achievement` first - this can result in an out of index exception because there aren't enough elements in `achievement`. Note that even accessing the `[0]` can cause this error if said `List<>` is empty.

To solve this, make sure you check the list size. This can be done via Linq

```
foreach(List<String> achievement in gdeData.Achievements.Where(l => l.Count >= 2)
```

or via an `if` statement

```
foreach(List<String> achievement in gdeData.Achievements)
{
    if(achievment < 2) continue;
    // Put the rest of your foreach logic here.
}
```

Comment: Oh that was so naive, I used GDE to make sure I was using 2 element long arrays, but accidentally added an empty array and forgot filling it! Thank you